# Responsive way of placing shapes behind an image CSS?

Tags: html, css

I drew the following:

[image]

I cloned this in HTML/CSS, but it's not responsive.

[image]

[image]

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./cat.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./reset.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="person">
      <img src="cat.png" />
      <div class="r1"></div>
      <div class="r2"></div>
      <div class="r3"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

### CSS

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300&display=swap");
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.person {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 25em;
    margin-left: 400px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

img {
    object-fit: contain;
    width: 100%;
}

.r1 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50%;
    max-width: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: #EFD2B4;
    border-radius: 15px;
    top: 0;
    left: 60px;
    opacity: .2;
    transform: rotate(-17.9deg);
    z-index: 1;
}

.r2 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50%;
    max-width: 230px;
    width: 230px;
    background-color: #E69868;
    border-radius: 15px;
    bottom: 100px;
    opacity: .2;
    left: 20px;
    transform: rotate(15deg);
    z-index: 3;
}

.r3 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50%;
    max-width: 230px;
    width: 230px;
    background-color: #A6BB9E;
    border-radius: 15px;
    bottom: 130px;
    opacity: .2;
    left: 200px;
    transform: rotate(8.12deg);
    z-index: 2;
}
```

What principles should I follow to ensure that everything resizes together? I am thinking I definitely shouldn't have hardcoded pixel values for dimensions, but not quite sure how to properly size this to ensure it's as responsive as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably better off giving the container (`.person`) a fixed/scaling size and then using `percentage` or `viewport units` to scale everything inside.

```css
.container{
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: min(300px, 25vmin);
  height: min(300px, 25vmin);
}

.child{
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

.--1{
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  background-color: red;
}

.--2{
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  background-color: blue;
  transform: rotate(25deg);
  opacity: .5;
}

.--3{
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: green;
  transform: rotate(-25deg);
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child  --1"></div>
  <div class="child  --2"></div>
  <div class="child  --3"></div>
</div>
```

The major benefit of doing so is that, once you've found the placement and scale you want, everything will stay proportionate to their container, and you won't need to consider max/min sizes for the children.

Applying this principle to your code might look something like this:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300&display=swap");
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.person {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 25em;
    margin-left: 400px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

img {
    object-fit: contain;
    width: 100%;
}

.r1 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 70%;
    width: 60%;
    background-color: #EFD2B4;
    border-radius: 15px;
    top: 5%;
    left: 5%;
    opacity: .2;
    transform: rotate(-17.9deg);
    z-index: 1;
}

.r2 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 60%;
    width: 40%;
    background-color: #E69868;
    border-radius: 15px;
    bottom: 5%;
    opacity: .2;
    left: 20px;
    transform: rotate(15deg);
    z-index: 3;
}

.r3 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 70%;
    width: 60%;
    background-color: #A6BB9E;
    border-radius: 15px;
    bottom: 130px;
    opacity: .2;
    right: 10%;
    bottom: 5%;
    transform: rotate(8.12deg);
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="person">
      <img src="cat.png" />
      <div class="r1"></div>
      <div class="r2"></div>
      <div class="r3"></div>
    </div>
```

Note that they now all scale in proportion to one another, and to your parent element.

Comment: Ah, great suggestion! So the absolutely positioned div dimensions are % relative to the person div as well as their margins?